# Format Button Sizes within a Relative Layout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am creating a feedback form, and at the end there are two buttons, "Clear" and "Send". This has to be done within a Relative Layout.

The problem is the buttons are not wide enough, I want the buttons to match the width of what is above them.

Here is the app before trying to change the width:

[image]

**And the code:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/feedback_name_hint" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:hint="@string/feedback_email_hint" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|top"
        android:hint="@string/feedback_actual"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    </EditText>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" />

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="@string/Clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="@string/Send" /> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

**I have tried to create a linear layout around the buttons, like this:**

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="@string/Clear"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="@string/Send"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**However, whilst the buttons are the size that I want, they jump to the top of the view, and affect the other elements:**

[image]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**SOLVED:**

It worked by surrouding buttons with the following linear layout: (note how Rating Bar is set to be above the `linearlayoutid`)

```
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout_id"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" />

 <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/linearlayout_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/Send" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
Replace your xml code with the following.

Here I have added `android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout_id"` to `RatingBar` and have put your buttons in `LinearLayout` by giving `android:layout_weight="1"` to both buttons

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout_id"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@String/Clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@String/Send" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This Should work

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt of putting them in a `LinearLayout` is correct. Simply add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the `LinearLayout` and it should work for you.

Update:
Also, change `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Can you post the updated code (with my answer). Also, make sure you clean your project since XML layouts sometimes have a tendency to not properly get recompiled.

Comment: Hey, now this sends the buttons to the bottom, but the other elements are still affected (the ratings bar appears over name and email address text boxes.. and the feedback textbox is missing)

Comment: It's hard to imagine what your new problems are without updated visual s or code.

Comment: Thanks J.Romero, it was very close (see updated answer).. some additional items were required as suggested by Manishika